# How can I make IntelliJ treat a .config file as an XML file

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

When I want to edit an IIS .config file, it seems that IntelliJ doesn't recognise it as XML and so I don't get any colour or code formatting. Is there a way to apply XML code and colour properties to a .config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Settings (`ctrl + alt + s`). Select `Editor` -> `File Types`. Select `XML` from the `Recognized File Types` list. Under `Registered Patterns`, press the `+` and add a pattern corresponding to your file.

Beware that this configuration is IDE-wide, so try to be specific if you don't want every `*.config`-file to be treated as XML.

Note: I'm using the newest IntelliJ IDEA version.